# Content type application/json not supported

Tags: java, spring

I am developing a rest API with Spring 5.0.4 and Jackson 2.9.5 with jQuery for Ajax call.  When I access my rest end point, I am getting Hyper Media not supported exception.
 It says application/json content type is not supported.

I have set contentType: 'application/json' in Ajax call. I have `@RequestMapping` in Test controller.

If I don't `@RequestBody` my method is getting executed with out exception. But when I add `@RequestBody` in my method params it is giving this error.

My json is `{"searchParam":"test"}`. I have a Pojo with searchParam property plus getters and setters, which I want to map my json to. I am using `@RequestBody` to this Pojo class. Can any one suggest?

Comment: You need to set consumes parameter of `@RequestMapping` annotation, in order to specify the application consumes `application/json`.

Comment: I have set that too. I have set  value(url), method to post and consumes to application/json. Still not working

Comment: Can you post your controller code, and curl request?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/testing", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) private void testing(@RequestBody RequestPojo body, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) { System.out.println(body.getSearchParam()); } CURL XPOST -v -d '{ "searchParam": "abc123" }' -H "Content-type: application/json"

Comment: Hope Jackson in classpath, Spring 5 automatically does this mapping right? I didn't configure any Spring to Jackson. Mapping. I just have those jars in my lib. Is it okay?

Comment: you might have multiple constructors in your POJO, Jackson requires only one `@JsonCreator`. In such case there's `415 Content-type not supported` error may happen.

Comment: is the controller annotated with `@Controller` or `@RestController`? if just `@Controller` you will need to specify content type

Comment: I have only one default constructor and it's plain java class. No annotations used. I am sending only one property searchParam and I have the same property in Pojo with setters and gettes. nothing else in pojo

Comment: Mine is Spring MVC with view resolver set to JSP. I m trying to write RestController in that project. Does it have any impact on Jackson processing. Do I need to configure some thing else. When I try to change data type to String the json is getting mapped to my parameter in Controller. When I change the @RequestBody parameter to Pojo, it's throwing this error. I think the error is misleading. Some Jackson mapping not working I guess, which I am unable to find